Undetected Selenium Chrome Python - High Data Usage
Wondering if anyone can assist with this. I have a script that works incredibly well and does exactly what I want. It will loop through 50 urls and download PDF documents. I have it set to loop and it's repeating this every time (with the URL changing) However, it uses around 2.5gb of data in 10 minutes. And I'm curious if there's anything more I can do with options to reduce data usage.
In short, loops through websites, closes driver at the end, opens new driver, repeat until end of workbook.
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, NoSuchFrameException, TimeoutException, ElementNotInteractableException
    import subprocess
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    import time
    import sys
    #  Add the driver options
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")  # Disables Popups
    options.add_argument("--disable-images")  # Disables image loading
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")  # Disables extensions
    options.add_argument("--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages")  # Disables extensions
    options.add_argument("--disable-features=Translate")  # Disables extensions
    options.add_argument("--mute-audio")  # Disables extensions
    options.add_argument("--disable-background-networking")  # Disables extensions
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions--disable-sync")  # Disables extensions
    options.add_argument("--disable-component-update")  # Disables extensions
    options.add_argument("--disable-features=PrivacySandboxSettings4")
    options.add_argument("--disable-javascript")  # Disable JavaScript
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.website.com/')
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    def kill_chrome_process():
      try:
        subprocess.run(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'chrome.exe'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
      except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass  # Handle the error case as needed
    
    # do smomething
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    driver.close()
    kill_chrome_process()
    
    time.sleep(3)
sys.exit()


you should use driver.quit(), not close.  Taskill won't be necessary unless something goes wrong.  The heaviest part of a Selenium task is the browser, so using something lightweight like HTMLUnit if you can get away with it, is going to be more efficient.

I kill chrome at the very end of my loops (only once) because another program checks to make sure chrome is closed before proceeding. Unfortunately I need to use UC because some of these sites I access have anti-botting measures. I'm not sure if headless works on UC. I will research the different between quit and close though. Thanks!

So when you call quit method, the webdriver first sends a command to the browser to tell it to shutdown.  Then it closes itself.  The webdriver cannot know when the browser's shutdown process has completed.  Some of that process involves cleaning up temporary files.  (one of them being the file that specifies the sessionID)  Not allowing that process to fully complete can cause some issues especially if opening closing webdrivers one after the other.  (Using a bit of sleep in between is helpful if you start seeing some initialization errors...)  Headless doesn't help much for resource usage.

Thanks, updated to /T, what a bummer. My process works great but it's such a data hog!
